# Spring Boot @ApiController annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller

I am working on my first Spring-Boot app. Got a working UI Controller implemented below:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Controller
public class UiController {

    private ProductService productService;
    private LocationService locationService;
    private InventoryService inventoryService;
    private CartService cartService;


    public UiController(
            ProductService productService,
            LocationService locationService,
            InventoryService inventoryService,
            CartService cartService) {
        this.productService = productService;
        this.locationService = locationService;
        this.inventoryService = inventoryService;
        this.cartService = cartService;

    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("products", productService.getAllProducts());
        return "index";
    }
    @GetMapping("/brand/{brand}")
    public String brand(Model model, @PathVariable String brand) {
        List prods = productService.getProductByBrand(brand);
        if (prods.size() == 0) throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        model.addAttribute("products", prods);
        return "index";
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such item")  // 404
    public class ItemNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
        // ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/product/{productId}")
    public String product(Model model, @PathVariable String productId) {
        Product prod = productService.getProduct(productId);
        if (prod == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        ArrayList<Product> ps = new ArrayList<Product>();
        ps.add(prod);
        model.addAttribute("products", ps);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I want to add a REST controller returning the same thing as HTML only I want the responses to be in JSON. When there is no data, I want an error return. Added the below:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@ApiController
public class ApiController {

    private ProductService productService;
    private LocationService locationService;
    private InventoryService inventoryService;
    private CartService cartService;


    public ApiController(
            ProductService productService,
            LocationService locationService,
            InventoryService inventoryService,
            CartService cartService) {
        this.productService = productService;
        this.locationService = locationService;
        this.inventoryService = inventoryService;
        this.cartService = cartService;

    }

    @GetMapping("/rest")
    public String home() {
        List prods = productService.getAllProducts();
        if (prods.size() == 0) throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        return new Gson().toJson(prods);
    }

    @GetMapping("/rest/brand/{brand}")
    public String brand(@PathVariable String brand) {
        List prods = productService.getProductByBrand(brand);
        if (prods.size() == 0) throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        return new Gson().toJson(prods);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such item")  // 404
    public class ItemNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
        // ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/rest/product/{productId}")
    public String product(@PathVariable String productId) {
        Product prod = productService.getProduct(productId);
        if (prod == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        return new Gson().toJson(prod);
    }
}
```

Apparently, autoconfig is working and my controller gets picked by the compiler. Only, I get the below error:

```
Compilation failure
ApiController.java:[21,2] incompatible types: com.rei.interview.ui.ApiController cannot be converted to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a simple mistake at the beginning of the controller.
The class must be annotated `@RestController`... not `@ApiController`

Change your code from

```
@ApiController
public class ApiController {
   ...
}
```

to

```
@RestController  // <- Change annotation here
public class ApiController {
   ...
}
```

The error

```
ApiController.java:[21,2] incompatible types: 
com.rei.interview.ui.ApiController cannot be converted to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
```

informs you that the annotation `@ApiController` is not a of type `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`